# Как оставлять данные в таблице, соединенной внешним ключем с другой Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
prices
---------------
p_id  title
1     Дешево
2     Нормально
3     Дорого
```

```
food
--------------------
id    name      p_id
1     Хлеб      3
2     Сметана   2
3     Молоко    3
4     Шоколад   1
5     Вода      1
6     Кефир     2
```

Они объеденены по p_id:

```
alter table food
    add constraint x foreign key (p_id)
        references prices(p_id)
        on update cascade on delete set null;
```

При удалении 1 строки в prices, ключи p_id в food станут null. А как при удалении просто оставить значение, каким оно было, чтобы food осталась неизмененной?

Comment: Это невозможно. Ограничения внешнего ключа потому и ограничения, что они не позволяют существовать значениям ссылающимся на не существующие записи. Для какой цели вам это понадобилось ? Возможно надо решать задачу как то совсем иначе

Comment: @Mike нужно, чтобы при удалении строки из prices - связанные строки food оставались в таблице, а связи удалялись

Comment: А чем значение NULL не устраивает после удаления. Ведь если в поле останется например 3, а записи в prices с 3 не будет, вы все равно больше ничего с ней сделать не сможете и не поймете что эта 3 могла означать